# Want to hide error message (View)

Tags: django

I'm matching the `name` in `Album Model`. And Its working just fine. But Some time It does not match. And It raise error message `Album matching query does not exist`. I want if no match is found. Then don't display any error message. Is it possible? Thanks

```
   def movie_details(request,slug):
    movies = get_object_or_404(Movie,slug=slug)
    # calculating wikipedia directory structer for images
    #image_name = movies.image
    name = movies.title
    album_name = Album.objects.get(name__exact=name)
    album_id = album_name.id
    song_list = Song.objects.filter(album=album_id)
    #image_path = generateWikiImage(image_name)
    #
    return render_to_response('base_movies.html',locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                              )
```

Error message

```
Album matching query does not exist
```

UPDATE:

```
def movie_details(request,slug):
movies = get_object_or_404(Movie,slug=slug)
# calculating wikipedia directory structer for images
#image_name = movies.image
name = movies.title
try:
    album_name = Album.objects.get(name__exact=name)
    album_id = album_name.id
    song_list = Song.objects.filter(album=album_id)
except:
    pass
```

Thanks  F.C.

Comment: just use `try` and `except` to catch the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment above, you need to catch the exception that's raised. In your case, it'd be:

```
try:
    album_name = Album.objects.get(name__exact=name)
except Album.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

If you want to set `album_name` to some default value if you can't find it, replace `pass` with code to set it to your default value.

([This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508888/matching-query-does-not-exist-error-in-django) also deals with a similar issue.)