# how to populate data of the models database into dropdownlist in django

Tags: django, database, django-models, dropdown

i am trying to populate existing data in the database  into a dropdownlist 
where i want just to make the data appear inside the dropownlist.

when i run the system it display the below error :

> DoesNotExist at / testmodel3 matching query does not exist. Request
>   Method:   POST Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Django Version:  2.1.7
>   Exception Type:   DoesNotExist Exception Value:    testmodel3 matching
>   query does not exist.

it says that the error is at line 14

```
tmn3 = testmodel3.objects.get(name = tmn)
```

1. i create class in models.py
2. map the page in the url.py
3. create form
4. create a template
5. create a function in views.py.

## models.py

```
class testmodel3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

## url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home),

]
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class drodownForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = testmodel
        fields = ('name',)
```

## home.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <tr><td>mouhafazat name:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name = "dropdwn1">
                        {% for testmodel in testmodel3name %}
                            <option value="{{ testmodel3.name }}">{{ testmodel3.name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="click" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from testapp.models import *
from testapp.forms import drodownForm


def home(request):
    testmodel3name = testmodel3.objects.all()
    print(testmodel3name)
    tmn = request.POST.get('dropdwn1')
    if request.method =='GET':
        form = drodownForm()
    else:
        tmn3 = testmodel3.objects.get(name = tmn)
        print("test for dropdown")

    return render(request,'./home.html',{'form': form, 'testmodel3name': testmodel3name})
```

i expect to view the stored data in a dropdown list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matching query does not exist Error in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508888/matching-query-does-not-exist-error-in-django)