# error: Dinucleotides matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I am trying to fetch specific rows from table on the basis of user input in forms. on pressing submit button, getting the following error.

**Error:**

> DoesNotExist at /search/ Dinucleotides matching query does not exist.
> Request Method:   POST Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/ Django
> Version:  4.0.6 Exception Type:   DoesNotExist Exception Value:
> Dinucleotides matching query does not exist. Exception
> Location: C:\ssrdb\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line
> 496, in get Python Executable:    C:\ssrdb\Scripts\python.exe Python
> Version:  3.10.5 Python Path:  ['C:\ssrdb\Scripts\chick',
> 'C:\python310.zip',  'C:\DLLs',  'C:\lib',  'C:\',  'C:\ssrdb',
> 'C:\ssrdb\lib\site-packages'] Server time: Wed, 14 Sep 2022
> 07:08:27 +0000

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from ssr.models import Dinucleotides
from ssr.forms import InputForm



# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def searchpage(request):
  if(request.method == 'GET'):
    form=InputForm()
    return render(request,'search.html',{'form':form})
 
  else:
    print(request.POST)
    if(request.POST['Motiff']):
       obj1=Dinucleotides.objects.get(SSRtype='Motiff')
       return render(request,'result.html',{'obj1':obj1})
```

Comment: Check similar question [matching query does not exist Error in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5508924/8353711) on SO

Comment: Looks like you don't want to get an Dinucleotides object with SSRtype 'Motiff", but with the value of POST['Motiff']?

It's a big assumption from my side, but can you try to change the `objects.get` statement into
`obj1=Dinucleotides.objects.get(SSRtype=request.POST['Motiff'])`

Answer (score 0):

first of all, pass data in function and then call query.